# Android Studio device dropdown stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: emulator, android-studio

So after some pause in mobile development, I decided to get back to it and so I decided to upgrade Android Studio to v3.3 as well (Windows x64) along with Flutter and Dart. Now my problem is that when I click the device dropdown `<no devices>` in the toolbar, it displays this:

[image]

And when I move the window around the loading item stays in its fixed position until I randomly click somewhere.

[image]

Despite this, I can still launch an emulator using the AVD manager, though it won't connect to the application because of this bug. The weird thing is, I also installed Android Studio on my new laptop, but there it does work, so it's probably a fault in my settings.

I've already filed a bug report, but does anyone know a fix or workaround to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reinstalling Flutter and/or resetting the Flutter SDK path under "File > Settings > Languages and Frameworks > Flutter".

Comment: Saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I spend time on this issue i got solution

Delete *platform-tools*

> C:\Users\ (computer name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

from this path

And download new Platform Tools from this site
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

then unzip and paste it on this location

> C:\Users\ (computer name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` and click `Invalidate and Restart` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812989/773718

- Make sure you have Power Shell 5.1 or greater (You can run this command to check $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
  Update Flutter, Dart and Android studio then restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Disconnect all physical android devices connected to the computer
2. `adb.exe disconnect` from sdk\platform-tools folder
3. `adb.exe start-server` from sdk\platform-tools folder

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

1. Close Android studio
2. open task manager
3. Kill adb process (on Task Manager on Windows)
4. Open Android Studio

**Solution 2:**

1. turned OFF your Wi-Fi
2. open `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
3. open command prompt from in this folder
4. type `adb disconnect` command in Command prompt[image]

5. Restart Android studio

**Solution 3:**

Go to SDK folder delete platform-tools folder.. invalidate and restart the studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can only edit your answer here, not on StackOverflow, please do it yourself over there.